# Improved Beastmaster?

Tags: savage-worlds

I have a player who has the beast master edge and also a minor pacifist hindrance, in my last game he asked to do an intimidate test of will to try to setup his dog for a defensive attack on a bandit that was attacking him.

Even though tests of will only apply to yourself, I really liked the flavor and decided to let him do it for the session and would look into weather we should try to make it an edge or if it was ballenced enough to let him keep doing it.

So the real questions are: 
Would letting a player transfer their tests of will to their companion warrant an edge? 
Should it be just find without an edge?
Should I tack it onto another edge like beast bond or leadership?

thanks!

Comment: I would have waited a few days before choosing your correct answer. There are multiple ways of approaching your question, and I know there are a few people on here who might have had a go at answering it

Comment: oops!  sorry. I have removed it... unless that's actually worse.

Answer (score 2):

As a house rule for Beast Masters and their animal companions, I think I would allow this to work for Intimidation (I am not sure about Taunt) without requiring an additional edge beyond Beast Master as it is (a) quite easy to justify narratively, and (b) it does not brake the game as long as the "only one action gets the +2 bonus" limit is maintained.

"*Careful with your teeth, Silver, we do not want this bandit to die as painfully as the other one... just immobilise him!*" is something that may make the bandit a bit wary of the dog, thus granting the +2 (or make him Shaken).

Comment: well, that's not exactly what i am asking, yes, the dog could intimidate, but I am specifically asking about transferring the bonuses from a test of wills between beastmaster and companion.  I understand that the beast could intimidate on it's own but the current setup is a pacifist with a dog for pretection, the idea is that he sets up his dog to defend himself with tricks or tests of will.  he just cant officially transfer tests of will bonuses.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I may have misunderstood what you need. Is it either (a) the master rolls Intimidate and if he succeeds the dog protects him, or (b) the dog Intimidates the attacker but the master rolls the dice (with his Intimidate skill, not the dog's)? In the former case I would say the companion will defend the master without any roll out of loyalty. In the latter, I see it difficult to justify this narratively and definitely worth an edge if admitted into the game (if an edge is needed to transfer bennies, much more for transferring skills). Or maybe I have not understood you yet?

Comment: He means that one does the intimidating, whilst the other can benefit from the +2. This is distinct from the way it normally works, where only the intimidator can make use of the bonus

Comment: Oh, I see! I had misunderstood it completely. I will edit the answer. Thanks @Phil.

Comment: Note to future readers: the four previous comments are now irrelevant as they refer to a previous version of this answer (quite different).